# Storing Japanese characters from TextBox to SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Storing Japanese characters from a form `TextBox` to SQL table appears as question marks.
I'm just trying to make a table that holds the Japanese text and the English translation to make my life easier as I'm studying Japanese.
Searching for a solution 2 days now nothing seems to be working.

I am not even sure if this is actually a good practice for storing text to data table.

Also column where I want the Japanese character stored is set to `nvarchar(50)`.

```
private void addWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  con.Open();
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();

  cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Words (WordJapanese, WordEnglish) VALUES ('" + newJPwordTxt.Text + "', '" + 
  newENwordTxt.Text + "')";
  cmd.Connection = con;

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();

}
```

Comment: What are you using to display the stored value? It's possible the text is being stored correctly but isn't being displayed as Unicode.

Comment: In general if you have strings that may contain non-ASCII characters in SQL Server instead of `"mytext"` you need to write `N"mytext"`. However, like the others have mentioned use prepared statements, which are much safer and you don't need to think about the N prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have missed the `into` keyword in your `Insert` statement, as a second note, you need to be aware that this kind of string concatenation is avoided and it is open to SQL Injection attack. You should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into Words (WordJapanese, WordEnglish) VALUES (@WordJapanese, @WordEnglish)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@WordJapanese", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = newJPwordTxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@WordEnglish", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = newENwordTxt.Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query has syntax issues and secondly you should be using parameterized queries to safeguard from SQL Injection.

The following should be good :

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Words(WordJapanese, WordEnglish) VALUES (@Japanse, @English)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Japanse", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = newJPwordTxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@English", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = newENwordTxt.Text;
```